# unit testing xmpp client

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, xmpp, jsjac

What is the main points of testing xmpp client?

I'm writing a chat, sort of XMPP client using [JsJac](https://github.com/sstrigler/JSJaC) library. Now I need to test behavior of my client after different server signals. For instance - that when server send's some error to my client - it would trigger `ondisconnect` callback. I also should test (in separate test) that when this callback triggered - certain conditions are met.

The question is should I do connection to real server in any test or I can somehow write some mock for it?

I can emulate server messages in such a way ([CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) code):

```
error = JSJaCError '503', 'cancel', 'service-unavailable'
xmpp._handleEvent 'onerror', error
```

but the problem is that xmpp object should be in connected state to do this.

Comment: Check out [Beautiful XMPP Testing](https://el-tramo.be/documents/beautiful-xmpp-testing/BeautifulXMPPTesting.pdf) (PDF) by Remko Tronçon

Answer (score 1):

For unit tests you should not connect to a real server - use a test double, e.g. a mock server.  You may also write some integration tests that use the real server to ensure you are connecting to it correctly, etc.